How can I make second argument path relative to the first on a command?
For example, let’s say that you want to copy a file like this:
cp path/to/the/file.txt path/to/the/file.copy

It’s very frustrating to write the path twice so is there something like this with a special character:
cp path/to/the/file.txt :)file.copy

It would be very useful especially if you are trying to diff a two file in the same directory

Hello, why are there 2 shells in the question? They could have different syntaxes. Questions should be focused on this network.

In either bash or zsh brace expansion can generate two (or more) aguments with the same prefix and/or suffix: cp path/to/file/{old,new} is equivalent to cp path/to/file/old path/to/file/new. For this case another approach is to temporarily change the current directory: (cd path/to/file; cp old new) -- the parens create a subshell so the parent shell's directory remains unchanged

I'm astounded as how this non-focused question with easily Googleable answer and also bunch of similar questions asked here got upvoted so much. The votes here are sometimes so random.

cp path/to/the/{file.txt,file.copy}

This expands to cp path/to/the/file.txt path/to/the/file.copy.

Yeah I use this all the time; small nit, you could use just cp path/to/the/file.{txt,copy}. To readers: you could use this also to hide files / mark them as old, for example: cp path/to/the/{,.}file.txt and cp path/to/the/file.txt{,.old}

Brace expansion is the way to go here, but for the sake of completeness, in bash, you can use a "special character" for it, but it is cumbersome: !#:$:h.

!#: this is a history expansion event designator for "[the] entire command line typed so far".
:$ is a word designator for the last argument. If you wanted to use some other argument than the last one, you'll need to use the count: :1, :2, etc.
:h is a modifier to "[r]emove a trailing pathname component, leaving only the head".

So:
$ echo /usr/lib/python3.12/pipes.py !#:$:h/foo
echo /usr/lib/python3.12/pipes.py /usr/lib/python3.12/foo
/usr/lib/python3.12/pipes.py /usr/lib/python3.12/foo

These particular designators also work the same way in zsh.

obviously yes, brace expansion works better, but thanks for teaching me about this. do these work in scripts, or just in the command line?

By default, only in the command line. You could enable history expansion in a script, but usually it doesn't make sense - if you enable it for a script you can't edit, you might break it, and if you can edit it, then just use variables instead

fair enough. It might be very useful for code-golf, that's why i'm asking :)
